English comedy movie parodying The Professionals, featuring the phrase "guv guv guv"
Does anyone know the name of an English comedy movie that was a parody of The Professionals? Some of the dialogue included the phrase "guv guv guv."

The obvious match is The Bullshitters: Roll out the Gunbarrel (1984), a made-for-tv comedy film from The Comic Strip that was intentionally written as a parody of The Professionals.

Commander Jackson, head of DI5, hears that his daughter Janie has been kidnapped and held for ransom. He calls in ex-agents Bonehead and Foyle (Peter Richardson) to save her. Since being kicked out of DI5, Bonehead works at a TV Tough Guys School, teaching others the "rules" of being a "TV tough guy", and Foyle is now an actor on stage. Jackson blackmails the two into working together.




